# I am currently writing code in node. It is showing error for specifying the path . what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is an image describing the problem I'm facing on.
[image]

Comment: can you post your code and the error message as text?

Comment: `mongoose` as in the [ODM](https://mongoosejs.com/)? Then why importing it from a local folder?

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose is actually a module that you need to install:

```
npm install mongoose --save
```

> npm --save argument write the "mongoose" dependency in your
>   "package.json" file

and like every node module you should import to your file like that:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

[Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't installed the module `mongoose`, install it by in your project folder:

```
npm i mongoose --save
```

Or globally:

```
npm i -g mongoose
```

And set your `NODE_PATH` variable to your node global modules path. And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mongodb` NPM module, which internally uses `mongoose`.

When you require `mongodb` in your file, Node Server start reading mongodb and import it's depended module. Since `mongoose` is not installed, so when Node tried to fetch this module from node_modules for `mongodb` an error is thrown:

> Error: Cannot find module 'moduleName'

You will get similar error every time on require a file or NPM module which doesn't exist.

To solve your problem just install `mongoose` using

```
$ npm install mongoose --save
```

`--save` is to save version of package installed in package.json, [read more here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

can use `npm i` sort for `npm install` in npm version 5.4 and above

If root user access is required

```
$ sudo npm install mongoose --save
```

Similarly for other related error for uninstalled NPM modules use

```
$ npm install moduleName --save
```